# Vuejs v-for not populating the select option value in laravel blade

Tags: laravel, vue.js

The expected result should return the id's value

```
 <select class="form-control" name="uploaded_segment_id" id="uploaded_segment_id" required="">
            <option value="">Choose Segment</option>
            <option v-for="uploaded_segment in uploaded_segments" value="@{{ uploaded_segment.id }}"> @{{ uploaded_segment.name }}</option>
</select>
```

//Output

```
<option value="">Choose Segment</option>
<option value="{{ uploaded_segment.id }}">Brand1_April_2017_April_2017</option>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html), this is the way to do it:

```
<option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.value">
    {{ option.text }}
</option>
```

So change this line:

```
<option v-for="uploaded_segment in uploaded_segments" value="@{{ uploaded_segment.id }}"> @{{ uploaded_segment.name }}</option>
```

to:

```
<option v-for="uploaded_segment in uploaded_segments" v-bind:value="uploaded_segment.id"> @{{ uploaded_segment.name }}</option>
```

Comment: 1+ Super Man Thank you so much.